# Gradle: Create a non-executable jar and executable shell script with dependent libraries as a package distribution

Tags: java, shell, gradle, executable

I am not a big fan of creating fat executable jars for java programs as it involves a massive overhead when I have multiple executable programs from the same project.

I want to be able to create a single library-like jar and create corresponding .sh scripts which pretty much have the structure of:

> java  -cp *classpath_libs* main_class program_args...

or any other executable where I can customize it to my needs but in a similar fashion(ex: `hadoop jar project_jar main_class classpath_libs program_args`). Is this achievable in gradle? if so, how? Note, I need to create multiple scripts using different main classes from a single project.

Key requirement here is to be able to use final fully resolved classpath string.

UPDATE: I have seen examples of using the **application** plugin but it creates an executable jar with dependent libraries packaged into it. This is NOT what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I have found, it appears there's no plugin that handles this directly. So, I used the `java-library` plugin, used the `configurations.runtime` classpath value and created the necessary scripts and the copy task to copy the libraries necessary into the necessary directories. For anyone interested, you may also try the `distZip` option in `application` plugin where gradle does create scripts for execution and package the necessary libraries in a distribution. You can take a look at the output of the script to see how the classpath is structured and create something similar.